# Passing columns and associated functions through dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to make my code more efficient and instead of multiple for loops pass columns and functions through a dictionary.

I have defined

```
months = ['Jan','Apr','Mar','June']
days = [31,30,31,30]
d = {'Month':months,'Day':days}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1

def leng_count(cell):
    return len(cell)

def add_1(cell):
    return cell + 1

dates = ['Month']
num = ['Day']
```

these two for-loops are working:

```
for col in df1[dates]:
    df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: leng_count(x))

for col in df1[num]:
    df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: add_1(x))
```

But my attempt to pass it through a dictionary prompts an error:

```
test = {dates:leng_count(x), num:add_1(x)}

for key,fun in test.items():
    for col in df1[key]:
        df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: fun)

Error: " name 'x' is not defined "
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This code doesn't define `x` except in the `lambda`S. What about `test = {dates: leng_count(x)...`? The code must define `x` prior to this line. Please post the entire stacktrace and a minimal reproducible sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
test = {**{date:leng_count for date in dates}, **{n:add_1 for n in num}}

for key, fun in test.items():
    df1[key] = df1[key].apply(fun)
```

You were getting an error "x is not defined" because you dict comprehension had no "x" defined in it :)

Here are two proper dict comprehensions:

```
{date:leng_count for date in dates}
```

and

```
{n:add_1 for n in num}
```

`test = {**{...}, **{...}}` - just merges both dictionaries together.

Also there is no need for `lambda x: add_1(x)` you can pass simply `add_1`.

Having nested loops here is also unnecessary.

Comment: shouldn't it be this `df1[key] = df1[key].apply(add_1)` ?

Comment: I assume OP wants to apply add_1 to 'Day' and leng_count for 'Month', so i packed both of them in a dictionary and apply it through `fun`.